Certbot `http-01` Challenge Fails with Unauthorized Error for Domain Verification
I’m trying to obtain an SSL certificate for my domain registry.cuongncc.uk using Certbot with the --standalone authenticator, but I keep running into an issue where the http-01 challenge fails. Here are the details:
certbot certonly --standalone -d registry.cuongncc.uk --preferred-challenges http --agree-tos -m myemail@gmail.com --keep-until-expiring -v

Output
Requesting a certificate for registry.cuongncc.uk
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for registry.cuongncc.uk
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain registry.cuongncc.uk
http-01 challenge for registry.cuongncc.uk

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: standalone). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: registry.cuongncc.uk
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 2606:4700:3037::6815:57b4: Invalid response from http://registry.cuongncc.uk/.well-known/acme-challenge/RuR-1jApRXG5MPzRCHacjG-x-PyyS2hMGnboqXdn8qs: 522

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the challenge files from the temporary standalone webserver started by Certbot on port 80. Ensure that the listed domains point to this machine and that it can accept inbound connections from the internet.

Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

I have checked

DNS Configuration: Confirmed that the domain registry.cuongncc.uk points to the correct IP address of my server.
Firewall Settings: Ensured that port 80 is open and accessible from the internet.
Temporary Standalone Server: Confirmed that no other service is running on port 80 during the execution of Certbot.

My Environment:

OS: Unbuntu 24.04 on AWS
Certbot Version: 2.9.0

How to I fix this problem?
I expected Certbot to successfully complete the http-01 challenge by serving the challenge file from the temporary standalone webserver, verifying domain ownership, and issuing the SSL certificate.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Try asking in Serverfault.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

[Solved]The issue was resolved by adjusting the security group settings in AWS to allow traffic to the domain. Here’s what I did:
Find the security group associated with your instance and select it.
Edit the inbound rules to allow HTTP traffic
